# preg_replace removes also line breaks when only spaces are asked to be removed

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, line-breaks

When I try to remove multiple spaces from a string by using this code

`preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $data)`
I notice that also line breaks are removed.

When I use a space character in the syntax instead of a **\s**, then everything works normally.

So I'm wondering why do we have this behavior and what is happening?

Comment: Search about what `\s` means exactly. Try to use `\h` instead.

Comment: \s is whitespace, tab and newline usually, so that's the correct result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: I never thought that line breaks are considered as white space characters. Anyway, that's the answer

Answer (score 1):

`\s` matches a whitespace character. From [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html):

> The default \s characters are HT (9), **LF (10)**, VT (11), FF (12), **CR**
>   **(13)**, and space (32), which are defined as white space in the "C"
>   locale.

Emphasis mine.